# Inherit from multiple partial implementations of an abstract base class?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

Is it possible to have a number of **partial implementations** of an abstract interface, and then **collect** these partial implementations into a **single concrete class** by using multiple inheritence?

I have the following example code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
    virtual void F1() = 0;
    virtual void F2() = 0;
};

struct D1 : Base
{
    void F1() override { std::cout << __func__ << std::endl; }
};

struct D2 : Base
{
    void F2() override { std::cout << __func__ << std::endl; }
};

// collection of the two partial implementations to form the concrete implementation
struct Deriv : D1, D2
{
    using D1::F1; // I added these using clauses when it first didn't compile - they don't help
    using D2::F2;
};

int main()
{
    Deriv d;
    return 0;
}
```

This fails to compile with the following errors:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:27:11: error: cannot declare variable ‘d’ to be of abstract type ‘Deriv’
main.cpp:19:8: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Deriv’:
main.cpp:5:18: note:    virtual void Base::F1()
main.cpp:6:18: note:    virtual void Base::F2()
```

Comment: +1 for the short, self-contained example.

Comment: "_abstract interface_" in general: abstract interface implies virtual inheritance (special cases can differ)

Comment: "`struct D1 : Base
`" Is there a reason why you are using public inheritance here? Is the use of `D1` of interest for client code?

Comment: @curiousguy no reason - just whipped up the example - in my particular use I use a mix of both public and private, depending on the situation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [inheriting virtually](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) from `Base`:

```
struct D1 : virtual Base
{
    void F1() override { std::cout << __func__ << std::endl; }
};

struct D2 : virtual Base
{
    void F2() override { std::cout << __func__ << std::endl; }
};
```

Without the virtual inheritance, your multiple inheritance scenario looks like inheritance from two separate and incomplete base classes `D1` and `D2`, neither of which can be instantiated.

Comment: "_incomplete base classes_" **abstract** base classes?

Comment: @curiousguy not necessarily abstract, just with at least one unimplemented method.

Comment: @juanchopanza What is an abstract class?

Comment: @curiousguy Aha! I get your meaning. I still struggle to think of a class with a bunch if implemented methods as "abstract", but I should respect the C++ jargon.

Comment: It is "abstract" because it is not concrete. **Concrete class can have instances, abstract classes cannot**, as simple as that. Have you ever seen an abstract class without any "implemented method"?

Comment: @curiousguy Of course I have seen abstract classes without any implemented methods.

Comment: @curiousguy You either don't know what "without any" means or you don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: @curiousguy in that case, I take it all back.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to have a number of partial implementations of an abstract interface, and then collect these partial implementations into a single concrete class by using multiple inheritence?

Yes.

Each `Base` base class subobject brings two pure virtual functions. How many of those base subobjects do you want in `Deriv`?

- If you want 2 `Base` base class subobject, `Deriv::D1::Base` and `Deriv::D2::Base` (so conversions from `Deriv&` to `Base&` would be ambiguous) then you will have 4 different virtual functions in `Deriv`: `Deriv::D1::Base::F1()`, `Deriv::D1::Base::F2()`, `Deriv::D2::Base::F1()`, `Deriv::D2::Base::F2()`. Only the first and last ones are implemented, so the two middle ones are pure virtual: `Deriv::D1::Base::F2()`, `Deriv::D2::Base::F1()`. You have **two entirely independent inheritance relations: `Deriv` inherits from `D1` and `Deriv` inherits from `D2`.**
- If you want only one `Base` base class subobject `Deriv::Base`, then you will have only 2 different virtual functions in `Deriv`: `Base::F1()`, `Base::F2()`.

Non-virtual inheritance in C++ is "concrete" inheritance, like containment: `struct D : B` means that for each `D` object there is exactly one `B` base class subobject, just like `struct C { M m; }` means that for each `C` there is exactly one `M` class member subobject. These relations are one-to-one.

OTOH, virtual inheritance is a more "abstract": `struct D : virtual B` means that for each `D` object is associated with a `B` base class subobject, but this relation is many-to-one, like `struct C { M &m; }`.

In general, for any derived class `D` (here `Deriv`), and for any virtual base `B` of `D` (here `Base`), all the base classes of `D` virtually derived from `B` (here `Deriv::D1`, `Deriv::D2`)  contribute to the overriding of the virtual functions in the base class:

- `Base::F1()` is overridden by `Deriv::D1::F1()`
- `Base::F2()` is overridden by `Deriv::D2::F2()`

Non-virtual and virtual inheritance are very different inheritance relations, just like if non-virtual member functions and a virtual function introduce different relations between functions with the same signature in derived and base classes (hiding vs. overriding).

Like virtual and non-virtual functions, virtual and non-virtual base classes must be used in different situations (and one is not "better" than the other in general).

### How to "fix" your code without virtual inheritance?

> ```
> struct Deriv : D1, D2
> {
>     using D1::F1; // I added these using clauses when it first didn't compile - they don't help
>     using D2::F2;
> };
> ```

Yes: using declaration control name-lookup, so they affect visibility and ambiguity issues, not virtual functions overriding.

With your original non-virtual inheritance based design, in order to make `Deriv` a concrete class, you would have to explicitly implement both `F1()` and `F2()` virtual function signatures (there are 4 virtual functions in `Deriv`, but with only 2 different signatures), so you need 2 function definitions:

```
struct Deriv : D1, D2
{
    void F1() override { D1::F1(); }
    void F2() override { D2::F2(); }
};
```

Note that `Deriv::F1()` overrides `Deriv::D1::F1()` and `Deriv::D2::F1()`.