# Defining multiple derived Interface Members

Tags: c++, interface, virtual-inheritance, abstract-base-class

I hope you can help me with the following problem.
I am trying to create a flexible system of interfaces and hit a problem.
This is the relevant code:

```
// Interface 1
//      this: virtual f_a
// -> abstract
struct I_A abstract
{
    virtual void f_a() = 0;
};

// Interface 2
//      I_A : virtual f_a
//      this: virtual f_b
// -> abstract
struct I_B abstract : public I_A
{
    virtual void f_b() = 0;
};

// Implementation 1
//      I_A : virtual f_a
//      zhis: defines f_a
// -> not abstract
struct S_A : public I_A
{
    virtual void f_a() {}
};

// Implementation 2
//      I_B : virtual f_a
//      I_B : virtual f_b
//      S_A : defines f_a
//      this: defines f_b
// -> not abstract
struct S_B : public I_B, public S_A
{
    virtual void f_b() {}
};
```

I cannot instantiate S_B because the compiler states it is abstract.
What is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662890/inherit-from-multiple-partial-implementations-of-an-abstract-base-class/11662963#11662963

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use virtual inheritance here:

```
struct I_A
{
    virtual void f_a() = 0;
};

struct I_B : virtual public I_A
{
    virtual void f_b() = 0;
};


struct S_A : virtual public I_A
{
    virtual void f_a() {}
};
```

Note 1: I am ignoring your `abstract` statements in the class declarations, since it isn't standard C++.

Note 2: There is a duplicate of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662890/inherit-from-multiple-partial-implementations-of-an-abstract-base-class/11662963#11662963), where you can find explanations as to why this happens.

Comment: Thank you!
I can now compile the code, but I am getting the warning C4250:

warning C4250: 'S_B' : inherits 'S_A::S_A::f_a' via dominance

What does it mean and what can I do?

Comment: @BetaCarotin I guess it is telling you you have diamond inheritance, and it tells you where you get `f_a` from `S_A`. But I don't use VS, and gcc doesn't give me any warnings.

Comment: Okay, I guess I´ll just ignore it then.  Thank you for your help!